# Sorting League Standings table

Tags: laravel, error-handling, controller

Am doing a league management system where the system generates fixtures and assign each match to an official who later enters results. Now when i have set everything possible for the log table but when i pass the results, am getting the some few errors : Too few arguments to function App\Models\Gamescores::updateStandings(), 0 passed in E:\Video\laraVids\laraProjects\HAM\app\Models\Gamescores.php on line 28 and exactly 1 expected

here is my code for the sorting of the league

```
    class Gamescores extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'gamescores';
    protected $fillable = [
        'games_id',  
        'away_score',
        'home_score',     
    ];

    public function game()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class, 'games_id');
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($gamescore) {
            $gamescore->updateStandings();
        });
    }

    public function updateStandings($league_id)
    {
        // Get all gamescores for the specified league
        $gameScores = Gamescores::whereHas('game', function ($query) use ($league_id) {
        $query->where('league_id', $league_id);
        })->get();


        // Loop through each gamescore and update the log table for each team
        foreach ($gameScores as $gameScore) {
            $game = Games::find($gameScore->games_id);
            $league_id = $game->league_id;
            $home_team_id = $game->home_team;
            $away_team_id = $game->away_team;

            $home_team_log = Logtable::where('team_id', $home_team_id)->first();
                if ($home_team_log !== null) {
                    $home_team_log->played += 1;
                    if ($gameScore->home_score > $gameScore->away_score) {
                        $home_team_log->won += 1;
                        $home_team_log->points += 3;
                    } else if ($gameScore->home_score == $gameScore->away_score) {
                        $home_team_log->drawn += 1;
                        $home_team_log->points += 1;
                    } else {
                        $home_team_log->lost += 1;
                    }
                    $home_team_log->goals_for += $gameScore->home_score;
                    $home_team_log->goals_against += $gameScore->away_score;
                    $home_team_log->goal_difference = $home_team_log->goals_for - $home_team_log->goals_against;
                    $home_team_log->save();
                }

                $away_team_log = Logtable::where('team_id', $away_team_id)->first();
                if ($away_team_log !== null) {
                    $away_team_log->played += 1;
                    if ($gameScore->away_score > $gameScore->home_score) {
                        $away_team_log->won += 1;
                        $away_team_log->points += 3;
                    } else if ($gameScore->home_score == $gameScore->away_score) {
                        $away_team_log->drawn += 1;
                        $away_team_log->points += 1;
                    } else {
                        $away_team_log->lost += 1;
                    }
                    $away_team_log->goals_for += $gameScore->away_score;
                    $away_team_log->goals_against += $gameScore->home_score;
                    $away_team_log->goal_difference = $away_team_log->goals_for - $away_team_log->goals_against;
                    $away_team_log->save();
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

thats my model where am passing the method to genererate the results

```
    public function fixtureToView($league)
{
    // Fetch all rows from the games table, including the related official model
    $games = Games::where('league_id', $league)->get();

    // Extract the values for the role column as an array
    $pluckedFixtures = $games->pluck('Fixture')->toArray();

    // Count the number of occurrences of each value in the array
    $counts = array_count_values($pluckedFixtures);

    // Initialize an empty array to store the duplicate keys and values
    $fixtures = collect([]);

    // Iterate over the counts array
    foreach ($counts as $key => $count) {
        // If the count is greater than 1, add the key and value to the duplicates array
        $fixtures->push($games->where('Fixture', $key));
    }

    // In your controller
    
    

    $gamescores = Gamescores::all();
    foreach ($gamescores as $gamescore) {
        $game = Games::find($gamescore->games_id);
        $league_id = $game->league_id;
        $gamescore->updateStandings($league_id);
        if($gamescore->games_id){
            $game = Games::find($gamescore->games_id);
            $league_id = $game->league_id;
            $gamescore->updateStandings($league_id);
        }      
        
    }

    
    $standings = Logtable::all();
    $standings = $standings->sortByDesc('points');
    


// return view('standings', compact('standings'));


    return view(
        'admin.league.fixtures.index',
        compact('fixtures', 'standings')
    );
```

thats my controller where am passing the method to retrieve it in the view, what i want is the log table to get the Id of the league where the games/matches belong to

the error am getting this error

Comment: simple, **$gamescore->updateStandings();** is missing the league id :P

Comment: alright let check